# Using IntVar in OR-tools

Tags: python, optimization, linear-programming, or-tools

I'm using Google's OR-Tools to solve a problem where some decision variables are integers while others are just positive real.

With `pywraplp` and `glp.Solver.GLOP_LINEAR_PROGRAMMING`, I set the integer decision variables as `IntVar`, whereas the other variables are `NumVar`

Upon running the solver, I get a feasible solution, but the solution gives non-integer values for the variables which were supposed to integers.
How should I use IntVars if i want to get integer values ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Linear Programming - Google ortools - incorrect decision variable final values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59116520/linear-programming-google-ortools-incorrect-decision-variable-final-values)

Comment: Not really, the problem in that link was for all variables being binary. In my problem, I need just a few to be integers, while others are to be decimals.

Comment: It is the same problem though, you can't use integers or binaries variables in GLOP.

Comment: But it does allow me to declare IntVars. What does that mean then ?

Comment: I don't think it can work like that with *_LINEAR_PROGRAMMING try to change your model to *_MIXED_INTEGER_PROGRAMMING and it will work

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into the same issue. Below code worked for me:

```
    solver = pywraplp.Solver("", pywraplp.Solver.CBC_MIXED_INTEGER_PROGRAMMING)
```