# Constrain some variables to whole numbers in OrTools LinearSolver

Tags: c#, linear-algebra, or-tools

Setting up a fairly simple undetermined linear system solution using Google OrTools (in c#). I'm having trouble constraining certain values to whole numbers. In the following code example, I'd like variables `a`,`b`,`c`, and `d` to be whole numbers, but `cash1` and `cash2` as doubles. Please ignore the poor variable naming!

**Code:**

```
// setup
double VTI = 221.17;
double BND = 81.92;
double CASH = 1;

double account1 = 10000;
double account2 = 5000;

double total = account1 + account2;

// allocation
var VTIAmount = total * .8;
var BNDAmount = total * .2;

var solver = Solver.CreateSolver("GLOP");

// variables
var a = solver.MakeIntVar(0.0, int.MaxValue, "a");
var b = solver.MakeIntVar(0.0, int.MaxValue, "b");
var cash1 = solver.MakeNumVar(0.0, double.MaxValue, "cash1");
var c = solver.MakeIntVar(0.0, int.MaxValue, "c");
var d = solver.MakeIntVar(0.0, int.MaxValue, "d");
var cash2 = solver.MakeNumVar(0.0, double.MaxValue, "cash2");

// constraints
solver.Add(a * VTI + b * BND + cash1 * CASH == account1);
solver.Add(c * VTI + d * BND + cash2 * CASH == account2);
solver.Add(a * VTI + c * VTI == VTIAmount);
solver.Add(b * BND + d * BND == BNDAmount);

// objective function
solver.Maximize(d);

// solve
solver.Solve();

// results
Console.WriteLine("Solution:");
Console.WriteLine("Objective value = " + solver.Objective().Value());
Console.WriteLine("a = " + a.SolutionValue());
Console.WriteLine("b = " + b.SolutionValue());
Console.WriteLine("c = " + c.SolutionValue());
Console.WriteLine("d = " + d.SolutionValue());
Console.WriteLine("cash1 = " + cash1.SolutionValue());
Console.WriteLine("cash2 = " + cash2.SolutionValue());
```

**Output:**

```
Solution:
Objective value = 36.62109375
a = 45.21408871004205
b = 0
c = 9.04281774200841
d = 36.62109375
cash1 = 0
cash2 = 0
```

Comment: `GLOP` is continuous-only (making it just ignore your integrality-constraints). See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59125270/2320035). Not sure if your or-tools distribution came with `SCIP`, `Cbc` or `Glpk`. But you should try those (and start with the first as some doc-examples show this usage and declare this one default).

Comment: I've tried `SCIP` and `CBC` but both say there's no optimal solution

Comment: The you already saw the effect. Feasible linear-relaxation, but infeasible when integrality-constraints are applied. You will need to debug your model as something is wrong if you expect feasibility.

Comment: With SCIP and a better model I was able to solve this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Changing the code snippets in the OG post to:

```
var solver = Solver.CreateSolver("SCIP");
```

And this:

```
solver.Add(a * VTI + c * VTI >= VTIAmount*.99);
solver.Add(b * BND + d * BND >= BNDAmount*.99);

// objective function
solver.Maximize(d-cash1-cash2);
```

Solves the solution fairly elegantly:

```
Solution:
Objective value = 8.22
a = 44
b = 3
c = 10
d = 34
cash1 = 22.760000000000446
cash2 = 3.019999999999982
```